# RadioButton JS_on_event callback + Recording data

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm quite new on Bokeh, and I'm stuck with some problems (which I guess are not very hard for someone more experienced).

I'm creating a figure that has a RadioButton with three options, an image_rgba (which is a map that I'm uploading) and a Div which I'm using now to "print" the pixel coordinates of the tap/doubletaps of my mouse).

[Current output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/451EH.png)

As you can see in the attached picture, I managed to "print" these coordinates into the Div, but I would actually like to also print the active RadioButton Label. (kind of:  "Elevator: x=300, y=200,...) Furthermore, once this process is done, I would also like to save the data of the Div into whatever document that I can extract and save (DataFrame, JSON, .tex).

I'm also attaching my current code here:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

def display_event(div, attributes=[], style = 'float:left;clear:left;font_size=10pt'):
    "Build a suitable CustomJS to display the current event in the div model."
    return CustomJS(args=dict(div=div), code="""
        var attrs = %s; var args = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
            args.push(attrs[i] + '=' + Number(cb_obj[attrs[i]]).toFixed(2));
        }
        var line = "<span style=%r><b>" + cb_obj.event_name + "</b>(" + args.join(", ") + ")</span>\\n";
        var text = div.text.concat(line);
        var lines = text.split("\\n")
        if (lines.length > 35)
            lines.shift();
        div.text = lines.join("\\n");
    """ % (attributes, style))


dims = im.shape
x = np.linspace(0, dims[0], dims[0])
y = np.linspace(0, dims[1], dims[1])
# create a new plot (with a fixed range) using figure
p = Figure(x_range=(0, dims[0]), y_range=(0, dims[1]),tools = TOOLS)
#plot.add_tools(hover_tool)
# add an RGBA image renderer
p.image_rgba(image=[im], x=[0], y=[0], dw=dims[0], dh=dims[1])

div = Div(width=1000)
radioButton = RadioButtonGroup(labels=["Elevator", "LOP", "Waiting point"], active=0)
button = Button(label="Button", button_type="success")
layout = column(button,radioButton, row(p, div))

## Events with no attributes
button.js_on_event(events.ButtonClick, display_event(div)) # Button click$
p.js_on_event(events.LODStart, display_event(div))         # Start of LOD display
p.js_on_event(events.LODEnd, display_event(div))           # End of LOD display

## Events with attributes
point_attributes = ['x','y','sx','sy']                     # Point events
wheel_attributes = point_attributes+['delta']              # Mouse wheel event
pan_attributes = point_attributes + ['delta_x', 'delta_y'] # Pan event
pinch_attributes = point_attributes + ['scale']            # Pinch event

point_events =  [events.Tap, events.DoubleTap]

for event in point_events:
    p.js_on_event(event,display_event(div, attributes=point_attributes))

#p.js_on_event(events.MouseWheel, display_event(div,attributes=wheel_attributes))
#p.js_on_event(events.Pan,        display_event(div, attributes=pan_attributes))
#p.js_on_event(events.Pinch,      display_event(div, attributes=pinch_attributes))

output_file("js_events.html", title="JS Events Example")
show(layout)
```

I would really appreciate some help or guidance.

Thank you for your time and consideration

Best,
Roc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below. You would need to filter yourself the HTML tags from the Div text (working for Bokeh v1.0.4).

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Div, Button, RadioButtonGroup
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

def display_event(div, attributes = [], style = 'float:left;clear:left;font_size=10pt'):
    "Build a suitable CustomJS to display the current event in the div model."
    return CustomJS(args = dict(div = div, radio_button = radioButton), code = """
        var attrs = %s; var args = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
            args.push(attrs[i] + '=' + Number(cb_obj[attrs[i]]).toFixed(2));
        }
        var line = "<span style=%r><b>" + radio_button.labels[radio_button.active] + "</b>: (" + args.join(", ") + ")</span>\\n";
        var text = div.text.concat(line);
        var lines = text.split("\\n")
        if (lines.length > 35)
            lines.shift();
        div.text = lines.join("\\n");
    """ % (attributes, style))

p = figure()
p.circle(x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
div = Div(width = 1000)
radioButton = RadioButtonGroup(labels = ["Elevator", "LOP", "Waiting point"], active = 0)
button = Button(label = "Download JSON", button_type = "success")
layout = column(button, radioButton, row(p, div))

js_download = """
var filetext = div.text;
var lines = filetext.split("\\n")
var lines_json = {}
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    if (lines[i].trim())
        lines_json[String(i)] = lines[i];

var filename = 'results.json';
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(lines_json)], { type: 'text/json;charset=utf-8;' });
div.text = '';
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
} else {
var link = document.createElement("a");
if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
    // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", filename);
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
}"""

button.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(div = div), code = js_download)
# button.js_on_event(events.ButtonClick, display_event(div))  # Button click$

point_attributes = ['x', 'y', 'sx', 'sy']  # Point events
point_events = [events.Tap, events.DoubleTap]

for event in point_events:
    p.js_on_event(event, display_event(div, attributes = point_attributes))

show(layout)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it's perfect to see a working example!

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Could you "vote up" if this answer was useful to you?

Comment: Yes I already did! (but as I'm pretty new to StackOverflow my up/downvotes are not shown yet). I would not like to bother you anymore, but is there an easy way to empty the Div? (I've added a button and it's own callback as you did for the "Download JSON" and I'm trying to find a way to "reset" it.  (I found things like "var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);" and other methods, but they don't seem to be working... Best wishes and thank you again!

Comment: In my case, this doesn't seem to make much sense as the div is sent from Bokeh, so I tried things like "var element = div; element.innerHTML = ""; but I didn't get any results neither.

Comment: OK. I see. To cleanup the div you just do: div.text = ""; I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know if it's the language or myself, but I find it pretty hard to get used to JavaScript and even harder to find "proper" documentation for it. Thanks again!

Comment: When using Bokeh plots modifying the DOM directly using pure JS or jQuery will usually have no effect. You need always to manipulate the BokehJS model itself by using references you pass to the callback or by giving an element a name attribute like "button = Button(label ='Download', name = 'download_button')" and than getting its reference with “button = Bokeh.documents[0].get_model_by_name(‘download_button’)”

Comment: I see.. but then, can you also use Python commands inside the CustomJS callback? For instance, if I wanted to load another image when pressing "Download JSON", I guess I should pass the Figure object (p) into the callback, but then how would you call the equivalent of "p.image()"  inside the JavaScript?

Comment: In a stand-alone page you can only use JS callbacks. For Bokeh server application you could also utilise Python callbacks that are executed on the server and the Python code is periodically synchronised with BokehJS models on the page.  Than each Python object has its equivalent in BokehJS domain. Please read Bokeh documentation, especially about BokehJS: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/bokehjs.html#userguide-bokehjs